# query in mongoDB to find user with maximum error

Tags: mongodb

I have data in JSON format and I need to find a list of users with the maximum occurrence of errors
in sorted order.

```
[
{"timestamp":NumberLong(1605595701),"user":"sam","error":"critical"},
{"timestamp":NumberLong(1605595701),"user":"john","error":"warn"},
{"timestamp":NumberLong(1605595701),"user":"sam","error":"critical"},
{"timestamp":NumberLong(1605595701),"user":"samual","error":"warn"},
{"timestamp":NumberLong(1605595701),"user":"john","error":"critical"},
{"timestamp":NumberLong(1605595701),"user":"sam","error":"critical"},
{"timestamp":NumberLong(1605595701),"user":"sam","error":"critical"},
{"timestamp":NumberLong(1605595701),"user":"samual","error":"not critical"},
{"timestamp":NumberLong(1605595701),"user":"sam","error":"critical"},
{"timestamp":NumberLong(1605595701),"user":"sam","error":"critical"},
{"timestamp":NumberLong(1605595701),"user":"john","error":"critical"}
]
```

so we need to find the list of user who has the most number of critical errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways eg using `$group`. One of the simplest way is

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 

  {
    $match: {
      error: "critical"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "count": -1 } },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2ND4gJkpivt)**

Comment: The given data clearly shows the each critical error based on user. So maximum no of user will give you the maximum no of error. Sometimes you need to specially get the **user && error**, a small adjustment you need to make `_id: {uname: "$user", err: "$error" }`. If you need to specify what type of error , then you need to use the `$cond`

Comment: If your use case doesnt satisfy the above code, please clearly mention what is the issue

Comment: I need to find a list of user who has the maximum number of errors but in your case not comparaing error.

Comment: may any user not have error in this collection? like `{"timestamp":NumberLong(1605595701),"user":"john"}`. May I know how do you validate is the user doesn't have any error

Comment: I did not think about this cause I only need to find a list of top ten users with the maximum number of error.

Comment: Does https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vetts4YuNVu help you?

Comment: this is just a testing tool and yes it helped me.